# How to detect from an iPhone app whether the battery is in charging or not?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios4, iphone-sdk-4.0.1

In my iPhone app, there is a requirement to know whether the iPhone is charging or not?

If it is charging then I want to display alert for the same.

So how can I detect whether the iPhone is charging or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setBatteryMonitoringEnabled:YES];

if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] batteryState] != UIDeviceBatteryStateUnplugged) {
    //Device is connected (charging or fully charged)
}
```

Edit: If you relly want to check if the device is *charging* (and not 100% full yet), use the `UIDeviceBatteryStateCharging` constant in the if statement. See [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIDeviceBatteryStateUnplugged) for more information.